# How to send Image and text messages to iphone using push notification in php

Tags: php, iphone

I know the code for sending push text messages to iPhone but I want to send text and image to push notification.  Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

You could send a unique ID corresponding to the images and text messages stored in a database.

For instance, after pushing the unique ID *91ec59771e83caf010a84af28a15a506* to your iPhone application, the application would go to the link

```
yoursite.com/ticket/91ec59771e83caf010a84af28a15a506
```

and download whatever you intended to push to the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send images.  You are limited in the number of characters you can send in the payload of the push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code

```
$msg = array
          (
            "image"=> "http://www.androiddeft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Shared-Preferences-in-Android.png",
            'body'  => $message,
            'title' => 'New Notification from Scamper Skills',
            'receiver' => ucfirst($user_name),
            'icon'  => url('public/images/system/logo.png'),/*Default Icon*/
            'sound' => 'default',/*Default sound*/
            // 'type'=>$notifications['name'],
            // 'click_action' => $url,
          );
$headers = array(
                  'Authorization: key=' . $token,
                  'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
```